# How are vectors different from arrays when used in recursive calls?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, vector

I have 2 very similar programs based on [this challenge here](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/56/). One uses arrays, one uses vectors. But their outputs are different. Even though algorithm is the same. Please explain?

Here is the code. 
Array version (output is 2, which is incorrect):

```
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 4

int step(int grid[][SIZE], int i, int j)
{
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > 3 || j > 3)
        return 0;
    if (grid[i][j] == 1)
        return 0;
    if ( i == 3 && j == 3)
        return 1;

    grid[i][j] = 1;

    return step(grid, i - 1, j) + step(grid, i + 1, j) + step(grid, i, j - 1) + step(grid, i, j + 1);
}


int main()
{
    int grid[][SIZE] = {{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}};
    std::cout<<step(grid, 0, 0)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the vector version (output 184, correct):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define SIZE 4

int step(std::vector<std::vector<int> > grid, int i, int j)
{
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > 3 || j > 3)
        return 0;
    if (grid[i][j] == 1)
        return 0;
    if ( i == 3 && j == 3)
        return 1;

    grid[i][j] = 1;

    return step(grid, i - 1, j) + step(grid, i + 1, j) + step(grid, i, j - 1) + step(grid, i, j + 1);
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > grid;
    std::vector<int> column1(4,0);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        grid.push_back(column1);
    std::cout<<step(grid, 0, 0)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first version passes by reference, your second version passes by value. Use `vector<vector<int>> &grid` to get similar behaviour.

Comment: Also, in the `return` expression, the four calls to `step` may be made in any order (not necessarily, and in fact probably not, left-to-right; and the two versions might use different orders)

Comment: Got it! Thanks! So use vectors whenever possible then...

Comment: @M.M Is there a way how I can make the array version behave like the vector version, but still using arrays?

Comment: No, you'd have to change to using `std::array`, or put the arrays inside a struct. C-style arrays don't behave like other objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version passes array **by reference** because it is equivalent to passing **pointer to array**. The second version passes vector **by value** which means that each recursive call vector is created on stack and you change **only local copy**. This change disappears immediately when you return from function.

You should use the following signature to pass vector by reference:

```
int step(std::vector<std::vector<int> >& grid, int i, int j)
```

Comment: Is there a way how I can make the array version behave like the vector version, but still using arrays?

Comment: @Eidbanger What do you mean?

Comment: @AntonSavelyev to make an array version to work like vector (i.e, call by value) you can pass the size of the array (number of rows and columns) as  parameters to the step() function and in the step() function you can rebuild the array by declaring a local array variable with the same size and therefore defining the local array variable by copying all values using  loops.